# A question on numerical range

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B \in {C^{n \times n}}$ and ${\sigma (A + B)}$ is spectrum of $(A+B)$.

Suppose

- $M = \left\{ {\lambda  \in C:\lambda  \in \sigma (A + B),\left\| B \right\| \le \varepsilon } \right\}$
- $F(A) = \left\{ {{v^*}Av:v \in {C^n},{v^*}v = 1} \right\}$
- $K = \left\{ {\lambda  \in C:dist(\lambda ,F(A)) \le \varepsilon } \right\}$ ,where ${dist(\lambda ,F(A))}$ denotes the distance between $\lambda $ and 
  $F(A)$.

Why does $M \subseteq K$?

Comment: Do you mean $A, B \in \mathbb C^{n \times n}$?  And $v^* v = 1$ rather than $v v^*$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if $\lambda \in \sigma(A+B)$ with $\|B\| \le \epsilon$, let $v$ be an eigenvector with norm $1$...

Further hints: $v^*A v \in F(A)$,  $v^* (A+B) v = \ldots$, $|v^* B v| \le \ldots$

Comment: I dont understand your hint, please guide me. thanks.